# Broken Eloquent relationship with extended model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model `Asset` with `documents() { $this->hasMany(Document::class); }` through a table `data_asset_document`. I extend `Asset` into multiple models, one of which is `Equipment`. In my seeder for Equipment, I attempt to create a Document bound to the Equipment record:

```
$asset = Equipment::create([...]);

$document = Document::create([
    'name' => "$type Purchase Order",
    'tracking_number' => app('incrementer')->current()
]);

$asset->documents()->save($document);
```

Eloquent produces this query:

```
update `data_document` set `equipment_id` = 1, `data_document`.`updated_at` = 2019-09-20 14:39:48 where `id` = 1
```

This is obviously incorrect, since `data_document` does not have an `equipment_id` column (Documents "belong to" several models besides Asset). How do I rewrite Asset::documents so that produces the correct mapping, even in its extensions? Or do I need to save my Document through a means other than Asset::documents?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing in regard to the relationship of Asset to Document.  The title says `ManyToMany`. The code says `HasMany`.  But the wording of your first sentence sounds like `HasManyThrough` when spoken.  Which one is it?

Comment: HasMany. Fixed the title.

Answer (score 0):

Since your extended asset model is called `Equipment`, Laravel expects your foreign key to be called `equipment_id`.  You will need to specify the actual foreign key of `asset_id` in your relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

**hasMany**

```php
documents() { 
    $this->hasMany(Document::class, 'asset_id'); 
}
```

The problem is, I'm not convinced your relationship is really `hasMany` since you mention what looks like a pivot table `data_asset_document` as being involved.  Many-to-many relationships, like mentioned in your title, would use the `belongsToMany` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through